# Pangu/PP Jailbreak Application Not Re-tethering my Phone

Tags: jailbreak, ios

So two weeks ago, I got the PP Jailbreak on my iOS 9.3.2 device. I installed it without the PP Helper software for Windows. I did it straight from iOS safari. It installed the PP Jailbreak application on my phone, and everytime I restart my phone, I have to retether (meaning that I need to use the app again to get my jailbreak back). Before, it was only a 20 second process, but now it takes me about 20 tries  before my phone is re-jailbroken. I install Apple Conduit 2, but I still do not understand why PP Jailbreak app doesn't work for me anymore. It just restarts my phone without doing anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

*Note: my Enterprise Certificate is still active, so everything should still be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

So after enough tinkering, I have found the solution. I am going to post it here in case anyone else comes across the same issue:

1. If your phone is connected to a power source, then unplug it
2. Run the PP jailbreak as normal (through the iPhone application)
3. Press the power button to turn the screen off
4. Plug your iPhone into a power source (this will turn the screen on, and the PP jailbreak notification will appear on your lockscreen)

Answer (score 1):

Reset Network Settings to Factory Default.

Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings > Click "Yes".

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: This answer did not help. Instead, with enough playing around, I have found the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way I found to rejailbreak my iDevice if the jailbreak crashes. Just open Pangu app and hit start. But if error pop-up message saying that Pangu is not available anymore, then go to settings, date and time, and change date back to date you jail broke yor phone, open Pangu, jailbreak, then you can reset date and time to normal again.